# How do I use the JavaCompiler in javax.tools to produce more detailed diagnostics or give me an exception stack trace?

Tags: java

I want to be able to dynamically compile a Java file and handle any compile errors and exceptions one by one. So I looked at [JavaCompiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html), and there's an example used to collect diagnostics:

```
Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = ...;
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();
StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);
compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnostics, null, null, compilationUnits).call();

for (Diagnostic diagnostic : diagnostics.getDiagnostics())
    System.out.format("Error on line %d in %d%n",
                      diagnostic.getLineNumber()
                      diagnostic.getSource().toUri());

fileManager.close();
```

This is all fine and dandy, except that the [Diagnostic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/Diagnostic.html) objects I get back are not very helpful in determining exactly what compile error occurred during compilation. There is a `getMessage()` and `getCode()` method that helps determine more specifics, but the API says:

> The actual message is implementation-dependent.

Which seems not very useful for portability, and if I was to parse it, I'd be doing it in a round-about way. So I'm wondering if I'm missing something when reading the API, or is there a better alternative to the `javax.tools` package.

Answer (score 1):

You don't get exception stack traces from a compiler. If you did it would be a sign of an internal compiler failure, not a fault in your code. I don't know what you're expecting exactly but the diagnostic messages are about all there is.

Comment: Ok I see why expecting a stack trace doesn't make sense. Though, I was also expecting to get more specifics from a Diagnostic. For example, I want to be able to know if it's a "Cannot find Symbol", a "<identifier> expected", or any other compile error. So, if I want to differentiate between errors then the only way is to parse the getCode() and getMessage() methods?